# Graph theory people at a round table problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So I have this problem:

There are 20 people at a party and each one of them is friends with at least 10 of the people.
They all sit at a round table. Prove that there is a way to place the people on the table, so that each one is friends with the person on his right and with the person on his left.

I don't even know where to begin,i tried to suppose there is no way and prove it's a contradiction, but it didn't get me anywhere, I've also heard about the 2n people around a table probability problem , but i don't see how it could help me. The idea my book suggest is to us a Hamiltonian graph but I'm not very good at graph theory. So any hints, ideas or solutions are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a theorem due to Dirac (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254218/hamiltonian-cycles-and-minimum-vertex-degrees) for a sketch of the proof) that every graph on $n\geq 3$ vertices such that every vertex has degree at least $\frac{n}{2}$ has a Hamiltonian cycle.  Consider the "friendship graph," where two people (vertices) are connected by an edge if they are friends.  This graph has that property (with $n=20$), so it has a Hamiltonian cycle.  That is, there is some ordering of the people $x_1x_2\ldots x_{20}$ such that $x_i$ is friends with $x_{i+1}$ for every $i\in\{1, \ldots, 20\}$ (where $x_{21}=x_1$).  Seat them around the table in that order.

Comment: So do I have to actually show a graph that does this and if so how should i construct it, or is this all i have to do and also as far as I understand i have to show that there exist a closed loop (a path that goes through each vertex exactly once)in which i+1-th is friends with the i and the i+2.This i have no idea how to prove.

Comment: The graph is *defined in terms of the friendships*, so you won't be able to draw a specific graph (since you don't know all of the friendships).  There isn't anything more you can do to construct it than to give its definition.  Dirac's theorem, however, tells you that even though you don't know exactly what graph it is, it has to have a Hamiltonian cycle, and this Hamiltonian cycle gives you an appropriate seating.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** You want to find an Hamiltonian path in the graph, where an edge is in the Hamiltonian graph if and only if two people sit next to eachother.